# Can't read the key from KeyStore

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I have some problems with KeyStore. I added key to KeyStore and can't get it from there.
My code:

```
        try 
        {
            KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
            keygen.init(128, random);
            SecretKey key = keygen.generateKey();
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("UBER", "BC");
            ks.load(null, pass);
            ks.store(new FileOutputStream(path), pass);
            ks.setKeyEntry(keyName, key, pass, null);
            System.out.println(ks.containsAlias(keyName));
            key = null;
            KeyStore ks1 = KeyStore.getInstance("UBER", "BC");
            ks1.load(new FileInputStream(path), pass);
            System.out.println(ks1.containsAlias(keyName));
        }
```

the output is:

```
true
false
```

seems like key disapper or I can't load the KeyStore corectly. Do you see any bugs here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are saving your keystore before adding keys to it.  Swap these two lines:

```
        ks.store(new FileOutputStream(path), pass);
        ks.setKeyEntry(keyName, key, pass, null);
```

So that they are:

```
        ks.setKeyEntry(keyName, key, pass, null);
        ks.store(new FileOutputStream(path), pass);
```

Comment: great answer, thanks! Works like a charm! Haven't seen I store before add key to KeyStore.